# How to make an auto embed system using youtube urls

Tags: php, jquery

I wanna make a system that auto embeds youtube urls into the page. For example when user puts a link of a video from youtube. I wanna make an iframe of the video. Any code lines is appreciated. Its jsy like adding video to a post using url only.

Comment: Checkout the correct marked answer over there [What is the most efficient way to load YouTube videos through jQuery on a user click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240946/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-load-youtube-videos-through-jquery-on-a-user-c). It may help you.

Comment: Saw that already. Didnt helped. Too different from what i meant. I just need to enter the url and it converts the url into an iframe and adds the video on a post.

Comment: yep, it is working with an `anchor tag`. you can use your own input (to enter URL) and a button (which will be used to trigger by click) and then get the value of input in your function.

Comment: Can u write an answer and explain briefly. Maybe it will help.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to include [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) Library in your Web page, and then:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="video_url">
<input type="button" id="loadTheVideo" value="load the video">
<div class="details_right" id="video_container">video place</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loadTheVideo').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var URL = $("#video_url").val();
        var htm = '<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>';
            $('#video_container').html(htm);
        return false;

   });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/sofc3e47/1/

> Enhanced the answer [What is the most efficient way to load YouTube videos through jQuery on a user click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240946/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-load-youtube-videos-through-jquery-on-a-user-c) as per @OP requirements.

Comment: Looks that u cant embed a video with a link. For example, like urs www.youtube.com/embed/+url. What if the url = youtube.com/watch?v=hdhshsh. The link will be youtube.com/embed/youtube.com/watch?v=hshshshssh. Which means its an invalid, it should be a code not a link after the /embed/

Comment: @James for user experience it will deal with the URL like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHfEakxwosQ` that will be entered into the input box by user. But on Development level, as per [Youtube rules to play their videos on third party websites they offer you to embed it](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en). So, The URL at user interface will be remain the same you as you wants.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy if you want to *only* do it with PHP.

Use [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match) the video hash from the submitted URL:

```
//$url = $_POST['url'];
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dl4bprs4dB4'; 
preg_match('/v=([a-z0-9]+)/', $url, $matches);

if (!empty($matches[1])) {
    echo "<iframe width=\"854\" height=\"480\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $matches[1] . "\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    // Outputs: <iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dl4bprs4dB4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
}
```